# Understanding the Relationship Between Stochastic Reconfiguration and Natural Gradient in Variational Monte Carlo

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, variational-principle, quantum-computer, many-body

I've been delving into variational Monte Carlo methods, particularly in the context of ground state energy minimization for quantum wave function ansatzes. In my studies, I've come across multiple references to "stochastic reconfiguration" as a technique to enhance the convergence of energy values.

However, I've noticed that the terms "stochastic reconfiguration" and "natural gradient" are sometimes used interchangeably. While I've found comprehensive resources on the natural gradient, such as [this article](https://andrewcharlesjones.github.io/journal/natural-gradients.html#:%7E:text=The%20natural%20gradient%20is%20a,of%20the%20function%20at), I'm struggling to discern its exact relationship with stochastic reconfiguration. Additionally, the mechanics of how stochastic reconfiguration facilitates energy minimization convergence remain elusive to me.

Could someone elucidate the connection between these concepts? Alternatively, any recommended readings on this topic would be greatly appreciated.